# Update product price on checkbox -> Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce, checkout

I have a checkout page, where I would like to discount total price if user check the checkbox.
I did a change on front-end, but I cannot pass the right value to do payment through ajax.

Could you please tell what I am doing wrong and help me?

```php
add_action('wp_footer', 'udpate_checkout_discout_price');
function udpate_checkout_discout_price() {
    if (is_checkout()) :
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($) {
                var isCheckboxChecked = false;

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    isCheckboxChecked = $('input[name="createaccount"]').is(':checked');
                    updatePrice();
                });

                $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name="createaccount"]', function() {
                    isCheckboxChecked = $('input[name="createaccount"]').is(':checked');
                    updatePrice();
                    updateOrder();
                });

                function updatePrice() {
                    var productPrice = parseFloat(<?php echo wc_format_decimal(WC()->cart->get_total()); ?>);
                    var discount = isCheckboxChecked ? 0.05 : 0; // 5% zniżki

                    // Aktualizacja ceny produktu na podstawie stanu checkboxa
                    var newPrice = (productPrice - (productPrice * discount)).toFixed(2);

                    // Aktualizacja wyświetlanej sumy zamówienia
                    $('.order-total .woocommerce-Price-amount').html('<bdi>' + newPrice + '&nbsp;<span     class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></bdi>');
                }

                function updateOrder() {
                    var productPrice = parseFloat(<?php echo wc_format_decimal(WC()->cart->get_total()); ?>);
                    var discount = isCheckboxChecked ? 0.05 : 0; // 5% zniżki

                    // Obliczenie zniżki na podstawie stanu checkboxa
                    var discountPrice = productPrice * discount;

                    // Aktualizacja zamówienia w sesji
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-ajax.php')); ?>',
                        data: {
                            action: 'update_order',
                            createaccount: isCheckboxChecked ? '1' : '0',
                            totalprice: productPrice - discountPrice
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            if (response.success) {
                                console.log('Zamówienie zostało zaktualizowane.');
                            } else {
                                console.error('Wystąpił błąd podczas aktualizowania zamówienia: ' + response.data.message);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
                            console.error('Wystąpił błąd podczas aktualizowania zamówienia: ' + error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
<?php
    endif;
}

// Funkcja obsługująca AJAX do aktualizacji zamówienia
add_action('wp_ajax_update_order', 'update_order');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_order', 'update_order');
function update_order() {
    $create_account = isset($_POST['createaccount']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['createaccount']) : '';
    $product_price = isset($_POST['productprice']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['productprice']) : '';

    if ($create_account === '1') {
        WC()->session->set('create_account', true);
    } else {
        WC()->session->set('create_account', false);
    }

    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();

    // Aktualizacja zamówienia w sesji
    $order_id = WC()->session->get('order_awaiting_payment');
    if ($order_id) {
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $order->set_total($product_price);
        $order->save();
    }

    wp_send_json_success();
}
```

Whole code is placed in functions.php. I am trying to edit total price, pass the price to variable and then send it through ajax and set the correct price by $order->set_total($product_price);, unfortunately, when I am going to payments, there is still old price...

Comment: Sorry, but in the checkout page, the order doesn't exist yet, so you can't update it via Ajax. Note that If an order has been created but not really processed, the order gets a pending status and is only available through the customer My Account orders via the pay button, but not anymore in checkout. The `WC()->session->get('order_awaiting_payment');` is only for the order pay page.

Comment: Could you please tell, what is the other way to update the total price? If not using ajax?

Comment: You can discount cart items prices, add a negative fee or auto add a coupon... There are many related answers on StackOverFlow.